# Django ORM: create ranking based on related model count

Tags: django, django-models, django-2.0

I have 2 models in my database: `Movie` and `Comment` (it has a foreign key pointing to `Movie`).

```
from django.db import models


class Movie(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=False, unique=True)

class Comment(models.Model):
    movie = models.ForeignKey(
        movie_models.Movie, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    body = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

What I am trying to do is create a ranking of `Movies` where the position is determined by the number of related `Comments`.

I can annotate number of comments and order the result properly:

```
from django.db.models import Count

qs = Movie.objects.annotate(
    total_comments=Count('comment')
).order_by('-total_comments')
```

This gives me queryset in correct order but I would like to do one more thing - annotate the 'rank' to each row.

So my question is: how can I annotate 'rank' to each row of the result? Note that it is required for movies with the same amount of comments to have the same rank.

```
|  movie_title | total_comments | rank |
|--------------|----------------|------|
| mov1         | 10             | 1    |
| mov2         | 5              | 2    |
| mov3         | 5              | 2    |
| mov4         | 3              | 3    |
```

I tried to use [window functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/#window-functions), as some of the examples seemed legit for me:

```
from django.db.models import F, Window

dense_rank = Window(
    expression=DenseRank(),
    order_by=F('total_comments').desc(),
)

qs = Movie.objects.annotate(
    total_comments=Count('comment')
).annotate(rank=dense_rank)
```

But running this query raises `django.db.utils.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error`

Comment: Note that you could also just compute the rank in Python since this is only for display purposes.

Comment: I will do this if I will not be able to get expected result with a database query.

Comment: Did you come up with working solution?

Comment: The problem which occurred in this question was caused by using SQLite db backend. After I switched to Postgres, the code started working as expected.

Answer (score 4):

`RowNumber` should be sufficient if the query is appropriately ordered:

```
from django.db.models import Count
from django.db.models.expressions import F, Window
from django.db.models.functions.window import RowNumber

qs = (Movie.objects
    .annotate(total_comments=Count('comment'))
    .order_by('total_comments')
    .annotate(rank = Window(expression=RowNumber())
)
```

But since the row number is inherent in the sequence of the records, Kevin is right in suggesting an easy Python method (e.g. `enumerate`) as you're going to be iterating over the recordset at some point anyway.

It would be different if you wanted a different ordering for your recordset than for the ranking, then it would make sense to use `Window` with a separate `order_by` parameter.

I'm not sure if `RowNumber` is supported by all backends.

Comment: Before asking the question I was using sqlite backend. Now I've also tested it on Postgres and the query from my original question works as expected! That's strange because it seems that sqlite [should support window functions](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html).

Comment: My query also seems to work on PG only, not SQLite, even though it executes fine in the SQLite shell. Window functions are quite new and possibly not 100% working as yet.